# cl error 0xc000007b when invoked from scons script

Tags: c++, scons

I am trying to compile a simple program using scons + MSVC compiler under Windows. Program source is just simple "Hello world".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

SConstruct is utterly simple:

```
Program("hw.cc")
```

When I run `scons` in the source directory, I get

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fohw.obj /c hw.cc /TP /nologo
scons: *** [hw.obj] Error 123
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

in the console and pop-up message with 0xc000007b error.

Aslo results of `where` command:

```
where cl
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe
where scons
C:\Python35-32\Scripts\scons.bat
```

I don't have any clue what's wrong.

**UPD**
[SCons debug output](https://gist.github.com/montreal91/6ed8cf810d814ebe4c4ee40adcb161d6)

**UPD 2**

[image: Error window when I run scons]

Comment: run `cl /Fohw.obj /c hw.cc /TP /nologo` in a console and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Compiler starts to complain that it can't find include files.

Comment: What version of scons? Do you have vswhere installed? If so where is it located?

Comment: @bdbaddog, I have SCons v3.0.0. vswhere is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`, but it is not in PATH.

Comment: try this in your windows shell:  set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=<path to a log file>, then pastebin the contents of your logfile and post it here..

Comment: @bdbaddog, I've added a link to log file.

Comment: Bring up a cmd shell via the start menu->visual studio 2017->Developer command prompt and then try your cl command from there. See if you still get the error..

Comment: @bdbaddog, when I run `cl /Fohw.obj /c hw.cc /TP /nologo` from dev console, I get `hw.cc` then `<long path>\include\xlocale(313): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but inwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc`. That's all.

Comment: Can you grab a screen shot of the pop up window and post it?

Comment: Add print(DefaultEnvironment()['ENV']['PATH}) and paste the output?

Comment: @bdbaddog, I've updated the question and the attached gist. I've added file with scons output, it should be available by the same link in the question as debug output. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Note the path SCons configures: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX64\x64, and the path you use on the command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe  Is your system 32 or 64 bits? (the hardware and also the installed OS)

Comment: @bdbaddog, sorry for long reply. My system is 64-bit. I'll try to fix path to point to x64 version.

Comment: Can you change the title of this question to indicate the version of visual studio/C you're using?

Comment: I can modify title, but I use MS Build tools because Visual Studio works very slow on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments with `cl` and `scons` I have finally figured out what was wrong and how to fix it.

First of all, `cl` should be available from the command line. If after entering command `cl` in the console you get errors like `command not found`, you should add path to `cl.exe` to the `PATH` system variable. In my case

```
PATH=<rubbish>;C:\Microsoft\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86;
```

After this you should set up variables `INCLUDE` and `LIB` to tell compiler and linker where to find include files and libs. And this part is a little bit tricky, because, to my surprise, `cl` does not compiling anything without Windows Kits 10 (whatever it is). Thus, you should specify its includes and libs accordingly. In my case

```
INCLUDE=C:\Microsoft\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Microsoft\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x86
```

When these variables are set up correctly, `hw.cc` should compile fine.

And, probably, this should do the trick for `scons` too, but to make one hundred percent sure it works correctly, `SConstruct` should be modified to something like this

```
import os

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
flags = ["/EHsc"] # Flags are completely optional
env.Program("hw.cc", CXXFLAGS=flags)
```

With all these steps, everything should compile fine.

Comment: This is actually a hack and not a proper solution.  If SCons isn't finding your install of visual studio then there is a bug.

Comment: If you use the "Developer Command Prompt" (found in start menu under Visual studio), it will set all these paths (and more) in that shells environment.  Still not the way to get scons to find the tools, but simpler than having to type these paths in manually..

Comment: @bdbaddog, actually, this solution is advised on scons faq site https://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line. And I use MS Build tools, not Studio. There is some script that should set up these variables automatically, but is doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Which answer are you getting that from? (Since I'm the maintainer of the FAQ and the project co-manager) It's not the proper way for scons to find the tools..

Comment: SCons should find the installation and setup the appropriate shell variables internally.

Comment: what install package do you use? (if developer command prompt is not available?)